# Unknown internal error in nodejs runMicrotasks()

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

When i try to run a nodejs program, i get the following error:

```js
node:internal/process/task_queues:96
    runMicrotasks();
    ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at push (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

REPL Node works just fine. When i try to run a js file i get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating windows 10 and installing a newer version of node.

Answer (score 0):

Because This error is caused when you call a function that expects an Object as its argument, but pass undefined or null instead
U can try

```html
If(obj == null)
{
console.log(null)//or return null
}
```